# Travis test keep failling saying this Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, karma-runner, travis-ci, mifos

Please we are facing a travis test on PR in the community-app. with the following error:

https://travis-ci.org/openMF/community-app/builds/230628985?utm_source=github_status&utm_medium=notification

please can someone give a hand?
we have give some attemps like

```
npm install karma
npm install karma-grunt
```

to fixe it but none of them  works.

### Thanks,

Comment: Lots of other people are experiencing this over in https://github.com/mulesoft/api-console/issues/275 -- in case a solution comes up there first.